# Accessing a NULL related models in yii2

Tags: yii2

In yii2 view I am accessing property of related model like below

```
$objPatientModel->physicianUser->diallingCode->phonecode
```

To explain it :

I have foreign key physician_user in patient table and in patient table I have dialling code (id from another table -- Diallingcodes) and in diallingcodes table I have attribute phonecode .

Now my problem is if in case value is physician_user is NULL then this throws the errors like 'try to get property of non object' which is because $objPatientModel->physicianUser returns NULL instead of empty object .I want to know is there any class or method that can be overridden in yii2 so that above error can be avoided without placing the checks ?

Comment: You shoudn't override this logic to return empty object. But if you are interested in, this logic realized by PHP magic method `__get()`.

Comment: @SiZE Is there any way so that I dont need to place checks?

Comment: Nope. You may `try ... catch` exceptions or place checks like `($objPatientModel->physicianUser !== null ? $objPatientModel->physicianUser->diallingCode !== null ? $objPatientModel->physicianUser->diallingCode->phonecode ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayHelper.

```
\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getValue($objPatientModel, 'physicianUser.diallingCode.phonecode', null);
```

It returns NULL  in case value in physician_user is NULL

[ArrayHelper api](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html#getValue()-detail)